# How do I combine ResponsiveDashboard with yo angular generator?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I am pretty familiar with yo angular and angularjs, but I'm going to try to make use of an open source bootstrap/angular/less template, and I was wondering if there is a right way to do it so that the template's building steps will be performed by the yo angular build steps

the responsive angular bootstrap template: https://github.com/Ehesp/Responsive-Dashboard

Comment: you can create your own generator

Answer (score 1):

you can tweak your generator using _underscore templating in your files, so they are build from generation.

you can use

```
 //             template                destination    variables
 this.template('yoTpls/_package.json', 'package.json', context);
```

being context

```
            var context = {
                appName:this.appName 
            };
```

and this being

```
            this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
                this.appName = props.appName;
                done();
            }.bind(this));
```